# Is it possible to record radio using headphones?

Tags: audio, hardware, recording

Disclaimer 1: I'm programmer, not a hardware expert, maybe – I just don't know – is the question completely stupid. 
Disclaimer 2: I'm not a english native.

With my MP3-Player I can record radio (in the sense of [Radio broadcasting – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_broadcasting)) using headphones.  So I wondered whether that is on Linux possible too.  I know that software isn't enough if the hardware isn't capable of it.  Some internet searching lead to nothing except internet radio.

Comment: You don't record radio using headphones. The headphone cable acts as an aerial for a hardware radio in your MP3 player

Comment: Oh … ok, my hardware knowledge is much worse than I thought.